# How to disable eslint on vue-cli 3?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli

I recently update the laster version [vue-cli 3](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli)

After creating a project and run it,
it will show the message

- You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
- Use `//eslint-disable-next-line` to ignore the next line.
- Use `/* eslint-disable */` to ignore all warnings in a file.

but in Which file should I put those comments?

I only have a package.json / package-lock.json and .gitignore on my root folder

Do I have to create a .eslintrc?

Comment: FYI, the special comments are a way of disabling eslint on specific portions of your code.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can remove the `eslint` rule by adding a `vue.config.js` file to your project with the following content.

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module.rules.delete('eslint');
    }
}
```

Alternatively if your project has a `config\index.js` file you can disable eslint by adding the following line.

```
useEslint: false,
```

Comment: Thanks, I created the vue.config.js file, then added your code. It worked!

Comment: This doesnt seem to work anymore in latest vue

Comment: Perhaps we can use this method now: https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/eslint.html#configuration

Answer (score 4):

This is work for me

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module.rules.delete('eslint');
    }
}
```

Comment: finally, after hours of trying all kinds of settings and ignore files, this is the one and only single thing that worked!

Answer (score 3):

if you are unable to disable it just remove it by using the below command

```
 npm remove @vue/cli-plugin-eslint
```

The below code is used to disable it:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module.rules.delete('eslint');
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would put `/* eslint-disable */` in a vue file to ignore eslint checks in that particular file. You can create a `.eslintrc` file to change the rules eslint should check for.

Comment: For details on how to configure eslint see https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: I put it in all my components... and still getting the same message
/* eslint-disable */ inside the script tag

Comment: even if I remove

"eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ]
  },

from the package.json