# How to disable ts-loader (tslint) checking in vue-cli 3 project?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

When I run `yarn test:unit` the process runs and then after a few seconds it shows `Type checking in progress...` and a long list of errors follows.

I tried following the advice to remove [eslint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49121110/how-to-disable-eslint-on-vue-cli-3) but it didn't work.

Here is my tsconfig.json (I don't have a tslint.json)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true, //noImplicitAny, noImplicitThis, alwaysStrict, strictNullChecks, strictFunctionTypes, strictPropertyInitialization
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["webpack-env", "mocha", "chai"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Could you attach your tsconfig.json and tslint.json

Comment: @MaximShubin done